# Get .txt file and parse it by new line or comma

Tags: java, android

I have a .txt file in this format:

file.txt (each line has text)

```
text1
text2
longtext3
...
..
```

I am downloding it:

```
URL url = new URL(FILE_URL);

                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();


                    // download the file
                    InputStream input = newBufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

How can I parse this `input` so I get the text in each new line?

I tried something like that:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
                        String line;   
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                    LIST.add(line);

                                    } }
```

but I don't want to save it,so I don't have the `File` instance

I can save in this format:

```
text1,text2,longtext3,....
```

If its more simple to extract it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an InputStreamReader (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Put it between your InputStream and your BufferedReader. Now you don't need the File instance (and so there is no need to save it first).

Something like ...

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    LIST.add(line);

    // further break the line into a list of comma separated values
    List<String> commaSeparatedValues = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scanner` class

```
String result = "";

Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

while(in.hasNextLine())
    result += in.nextLine() + ",";
```

this will create a string like this:

`text1,text2,longtext3,....`

Comment: Don't use String concatenation. You'll be left with dozens. hundreds of even thousands of String instances (depending on file size), waiting for gc to delete them. Waste of memory and time.

Better use StringBuilder#append instead (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but I think you want to save each line of a text file. This worked for me, it puts every line into one long string.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    String FILE_URL = "http://www.google.com/robots.txt";
    String FILE_CONTENTS = "";
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(FILE_URL);

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();


        // download the file
        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());   

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while( line != null ) 
        {
            FILE_CONTENTS += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch( MalformedURLException e ) 
    {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL" );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "IOException" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to scan as normal text and replace every '\n' in a comma...